# Unable to save pdf form data using PDFKit iOS 11

Tags: objective-c, ios-pdfkit

I have loaded a pdf form using PDFKit in iOS 11. I am trying to save the editable fields ( Checkbox, TextBox) values.
How do I get back the editable PDFDocument object to save the PDF contents using

- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path;

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I did something like this. I added and Observer and on receiving notification when the pdf changes write the contents to a filepath

```
PDFView *view = notification.object;
PDFDocument *myDocument = view.document;
NSData* content = myDocument.dataRepresentation; 
[content writeToFile:newPath atomically:YES];
```

That worked for me.

Comment: Try to reload your pdf document from the path you write to  NSURL *newURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:newPath];
        pdfdocument = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL:newURL];